# Is there a way to capture scroll events on a List-View in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I'm using a grid layout for a List View for a simple RSS reader, and want to reload the list if the user scrolls past the top (standard Android design pattern).

From the `ui/gestures` module I've tried the swipe and pan gestures, but I haven't been able to determine the scroll position from those. for example:

**XML**

```
<ListView pan="myFunc"items="{{ myItems }}">
    <ListView.itemTemplate>
        <GridLayout columns="*,3*" rows="*,2*">
            ...
        </GridLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunc(args){
    if(args.deltaY > 0 && args.deltaX > -10 && args.deltaX < 10){
        console.log('swiping down');
    }
}
```

invokes `myFunc` and I can determine `deltaY`, but I'm not sure how to find the vertical offset from it's `args` object to tell if the user is trying to scroll past the top.

I saw the `ui/scroll-view` module, but I don't know how that will interact with my `GridLayout` and `ListView`.

New to this project, and it feels like I'm overlooking something simple.

Would be grateful for any insight. Thanks!

Comment: There is already an open [issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/724) in {N} GitHub repository, where you can contribute to the discussion.